# svn: concern with changing codes in svn and directly on the server

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Yesterday I changed a css file through ssh, I put some codes in the file:

```
#c285{
    margin-top: 33px;
    float: right;
}
```

And today I am wondering how will it be if i do it through svn, so today I checked out the source code, and did a test, i put some code in this file:

```
#35{
  clear: both;
}
```

Then I committed this css file through tortoiseSVN, I found result is like this:

a. css file on server
has both `#c285` and  `#35`

b. css file in svn
only has `#35`

So my questions are:

1.Does this mean? if I change codes in ssh, later on if I do not touch this code(`#c285`) in svn, it will stay there, if I change it in svn it will be overwritten?

2.Later on, if I need to publish it, will the changes done by ssh be published or only changes in svn?

Comment: Never. Ever. Ever. make changes directly.  Always go through source control.  You also don't want to deploy with 'svn up' - as you learned sooner or later somebody (you) will screw it up.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like you have a working copy checkout on your web server.  When you edited the file on the web server you made a local change to the file there.

Later you updated a file on a separate working copy on your local machine and committed it to SVN.  Then you or some automated process ran `svn update` on the working copy on the web server.

Your local modification to the working copy will remain when you update, the output of the update will typically show a line starting with G to show that the changes from the svn server have been merGed with your local changes.  However, if your changes conflict (modify the same lines) as your local change then it will show with a C (as in Conflict) and then the file in the working copy will have formatting to show you which sides have what data so you can resolve the conflict.

Based on how you appear to be using Subversion you should avoid modifying the working copy on the web server.  Doing so risks your changes creating conflicts and thus breaking your file (you'll have conflict markers in your file which will be invalid css).  You may want to read about handling conflicts here:
http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.tour.cycle.html#svn.tour.cycle.resolve

You can use the `svn status` command to see if there are local modifications to the working copy.  You may want to read this section of the svnbook for details on the status command:
http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.tour.cycle.html#svn.tour.cycle.examine

I can't answer your second question because I have no idea what the action "publish" means in the context of your setup.  You'd need to share more details of how you have things working or possibly discuss this with whoever set this up if you don't know the details.

I'd also suggest that you read the explanation of the copy-modify-merge workflow in the svnbook:
http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.basic.version-control-basics.html#svn.basic.vsn-models.copy-merge